# How to change this a href in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change the URL for of the current a href code to match `https://google.com/`. I tried adding URL after href=" in the code below, but the hyperlink just disappeared from the page.

```
printf(
  __(
      '%sChange your membership plan.%s',
      'wc-multivendor-membership'
    ),
    '<a style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 20px; margin-left: 10px; color: #00897b;" target="_blank" href="'
    .apply_filters(
      'wcfm_change_membership_url',
      get_wcfm_membership_url()
    )
    .'">', 
    '</a>'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably missed a quote. Try this:

```
printf(
    __(
        '%sChange your membership plan.%s',
        'wc-multivendor-membership'
    ),
    '<a style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 20px; margin-left: 10px; color: #00897b;" target="_blank" href="https://google.com/">', 
    '</a>'
);
```